# Dynamic site title

Tags: php, dynamic, title

I created this dynamic site. It works almost fine, but I have one problem.
How can I have a invidiual title for each page (in the html  tag).
I hope you understand what I mean.
Take a look at my index.php

```
<html>
    <?php
    include_once 'config.php';
    include_once 'includes/mysqlconnect.php';
    $url_slash=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url= rtrim($url_slash, '/');
    //$url = basename($url);
    ?>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>KasCraft | *********</title> //Here I need a variable or some other to display the title for each site
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $domain;?>themes/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $domain;?>themes/<?php echo $theme;?>.css">
    </head>
    <body class="body">
        <div class="container-all">
            <?php include_once 'includes/header.php';?>
            <div class="container">
                <?php include_once 'includes/navigationbar.php';?>
                <?php include_once 'includes/rightsidebar.php';?>
                <div class="content"><?php

                if ($url==''){

                    include_once "sites/home.php";
                }
                elseif (file_exists("sites/$url.php") && is_readable('/var/www/html/sites/'.$url.'.php')){
                    include_once '/var/www/html/sites/'.$url.'.php';

                }

                else {
                    include_once 'sites/404.php';

                }


                ?></div>
                <?php include_once 'includes/footer.php';?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody please help me.

Comment: Do NEVER - again NEVER - include something you got from your user. Someone may inject something like '../../../etc/passwd' as `$url`. Or even worse, may upload a php file named something.jpg to your server (e.g. via some Web app) and then include this evil code. Again: NEVER include files you got from external data sources.

Comment: 1. Its not external files. 2. I tested this with mydomain.com/../../../etc/virc and the file dosent shows. But can you please answer my question??

Comment: $url is coming from REQUEST_URI, so it's external.